# How to send a mail via plugin using templates in shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I created a plugin in which I would like to send a Mail to a customer.

It would be really convenient to use the email templates, since they are editable in the admin panel. The problem here is that the email templates need a type and I could not find a generic type, but only specific ones.

Should I create my own email template type? Or is there another way to use a template? Do I have to do it without Templates?

[I have also found a really useful tutorial.](https://shopwarian.com/how-to-send-emails-from-shopware-6-programmatically/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new type of email template which you can then select in the admin panel, you have to use a migration. See [here for an example](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/7b405dce1c8af87ed51c84cd3dd4400716a51460/src/Core/Migration/V6_3/Migration1562240231UserPasswordRecovery.php#L50).

Then you can use the description in the section "An advanced email service for Shopware 6" in the tutorial to trigger the mail.